# Error while connecting Z3 solver to KeY 2.8.0. in command line

Tags: z3, key-formal-verification

I am new to KeY and am trying to set everything up so that I can start verification procedures. To do so, I need to enable SMT Solver: Z3. I downloaded the Z3 file, but when filling in the directory path in the command line in the Z3 settings in KeY, get the error "null" (see screenshot). I have tried many different locations for my Z3.exe file and still get the same error. I got the directory path by going to the file --> right-click --> press option key (macbook) --> copy path.

Is there someone who knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rce9E.png)
(name removed for privacy)

Comment: I have never worked with KeY, but you mention the Macbook option key while your Z3 path looks like you downloaded the Windows version.